# Monitor email service with data feed: email report

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service, email-alert, logging

I am surprised I do not find find any examples of best practices on this matter. So, I have feeling maybe I am doing something wrong.

We have email service which is receiving emails with CSV file attached. The service is supposed to process this file and produce new records. Ideally, I'd like to receive a report on a process of the data feed :

1. If it is successful: email with data received, data created and logs.
2. If it is unsuccessful: email with data received, and logs.

What are the best practices on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Apex can be used to Parse CSV files. However, I am not very sure how it would send you the email with the data created. 
In my opinion, it can parse the csv and create the records. After that, you can use the API to get the records using SOQL and you can store it as a String in one of the Long Text Area fields.
Then you can send an email to yourself and specify the value of the Long Text Area field in the body of the email.

If there is an error message, then you can use the same kind of functionality under try/ctch block. Also, you can use savepoints as well.

You can refer to the following links for example of code:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Code_Samples#Parse_a_CSV_with_APEX
- http://www.infallibletechie.com/2012/08/parsing-csv-to-sobject-using-apex-in.html
- http://developer.financialforce.com/customizations/importing-large-csv-files-via-batch-apex/
- https://github.com/gautamsalesforce/parsecsvinsalesforce

/* Please mark this as an answer if it answers your question */